# Microsoft VBA Editor has a white box in the middle

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-word, vba

I'm using Microsoft Word 2016 and Microsoft Excel 2016 for Mac OSX.

Visual Basic Editor is covered by a white box which prevents me from doing basic editing to write a macro.

I can't figure out how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest looking onto that answer below and giving it a green check. I've never seen this, but then again I use the native computer that this technology lives on, PC.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a white box. The editor margins are so narrow that you only see one character per line.

See this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377477/margins-in-visual-basic-editor-excel-2016) and this [Microsoft Cummunity question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/visual-basic-editor-single-column-bug/3d8d114d-7c26-4deb-b893-c55c400397b4). Both suggest updating Office to the latest version fixes this bug.

Comment: Or downgrade to Office 2011 for Mac and get something that resembles a workable VBE.